# Using ST_Transform() to get the length of a LineString using SRID 4326 returning very small numbers

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, openmaptiles

I am using `openmaptiles` to convert OSM `pbf` files to `mbtiles`. I am testing a trail that is about 5 miles in length. In doing this, I am wanting to calculate the length of `path` using the following:

```
ST_AsText(ST_Transform(geometry, 4326)::geography)
```

This returns the geometry as text, which isn't what I want:

[image]

If I cast to `text`, I get a very small number such as `0.086`.:

```
ST_Length(ST_Transform(geometry, 4326))::text
```

It seems that this is in geodesic distances.

**How would I convert the geodesic distance into meters?**

Comment: You forgot to cast the WGS84 to `geography`

Comment: @Vince Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: You *want* geodesic distances. You're getting Cartesian degrees (which are useless). See http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geography.html

Comment: `st_length(st_transform(geometry,4326)::geography)::text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length you're getting from `st_length(st_transform(geometry,4326))` is in degrees of rotation along the curve of the earth.  Imagine a point at the center of the earth, then draw a line from the center to the start point and the center to the end point.  The angle between those lines is the value you're getting.  What you want is to convert that distance in degrees to the distance in meters.  You need a distance from the center point and a reference curve for that, which casting to geography provides.

[image: https://www.shsu.edu/~dl_www/bkonline/GenRef111/Reading/RefL01Maps/Lab01index.htm]

**Cast your geometry to geography in order to use the spheroid to calculate the distance in meters:**

```
st_length(st_transform(geometry,4326)::geography)::text
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just use this: `ST_LENGTH(geometry::geography)`